# React component is not rerendered after setting new state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple component, which should update the value of the text area when new text is dropped on it. It is correctly showing the "default" value on initial render, but is not rerendered on drop event. In the console I see the new text value and "drop!" are logged as expected. Why the component is not rerendered?

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd'
import { useState } from "react";

const CodeArea = (props) => {
  const [areaValue, setAreaValue] = useState("default");

  function addText(item) {
    // document.getElementById("myTextArea").value = 
    //   document.getElementById("myTextArea").value + item.text;
    console.log("drop!")
    console.log(item.text)
    setAreaValue(item.text);        
  }

  const [ , drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: "block",
    drop: (item) => addText(item)
  }))

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <textarea
        ref={drop}
        id="myTextArea"
        name="myTextArea"
        rows="25"
        cols="50"
      >
        {areaValue}
      </textarea>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

CodeArea.propTypes = {
};

export default CodeArea
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the value of textarea attribute, like this:

```html
<textarea ref={drop} id="myTextArea" name="myTextArea" rows="25" cols="50" value={areaValue}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it freezes the textArea, it does not allow manual input. Is there a way to allow the input?

Comment: use the onChange event to change the from the textarea

Answer (score 1):

The `textarea` element you are rendering is uncontrolled, so updating the `areaValue` state won't update it.

See:

- [Controlling a text area with a state variable](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/textarea#controlling-a-text-area-with-a-state-variable)
- [My text area doesn't update when I type into it](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/textarea#my-text-area-doesnt-update-when-i-type-into-it)

Instead of trying to render the `areaValue` as a child of `textarea`, pass is as the `value` prop. To allow manual editing of the text, use an `onChange` handler.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import { useState } from "react";;

const CodeArea = () => {
  const [areaValue, setAreaValue] = useState("default");

  const addText = (item) => setAreaValue(item.text);
  const changeHandler = e => setAreaValue(e.target.value);

  const [, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: "block",
    drop: addText,
  }));

  return (
    <textarea
      ref={drop}
      id="myTextArea"
      name="myTextArea"
      rows="25"
      cols="50"
      value={areaValue}        // <-- control input value
      onChange={changeHandler} // <--respond to changes
    />
  );
};
```